# Are winter babies better at music?

Tags: music

I heard on a Fox News commercial that "winter babies are better at music".

I want to know if there are any studies on this subject.

Comment: Related claim: [Winter babies are just plain better](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/babies-born-in-winter-are-bigger-brighter-and-more-successful-523070.html)

Comment: It's not just biological either - the academic year is arranged to suit subsistence farmers, and this causes a [lifelong disadvantage for summer babies](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-23435439)

Comment: Not a real answer, so I post it as a comment: I wrote a quick and dirty program to look at the birthdays of an fairly arbitrary sample of 2254 instrumentalists on Wikipedia (mostly Jazz and classical musicians). This data shows no statistically significant variation over the year. This is not really a proper analysis, but it makes me confident in assuming that at least your chances of becoming a famous Jazz musician are not greatly reduced by being born in summer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/y9mDg.png

Comment: @Emil, pretty good analysis. You should probably have provided it as an answer.